# Getting error on axios post call success and error in React Testing

Tags: reactjs, testing, axios

So Im new to react and want to check my code , my code is working fine but fails in testing
need help

I want the data entered my user in the form to post to json-server using axios
my code is posting data to the server but it fails in testing

where to update in my code

Testing File

```
describe("Testing Booking component post http call", () => {
  const server = setupServer(
    rest.post("http://localhost:4000/bookings", (req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(
        ctx.json({
          bookedOn: "2022-03-25",
          buffetName: "SouthIndianFestivalSpecial",
          emailId: "kavya@gmail.com",
          id: 1018,
          plateCount: "2",
        })
      );
    })
  );

  beforeAll(() => server.listen());
  afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
  afterAll(() => server.close());
  it("Testing axios post call success", async () => {
    render(<BookingComponent />);
    let buffetName = screen.getByTestId("buffetName");
    fireEvent.change(buffetName, {
      target: { value: "SouthIndianFestivalSpecial" },
    });
    let email = screen.getByTestId("emailId");
    fireEvent.change(email, { target: { value: "kavya@gmail.com" } });
    let plateCount = screen.getByTestId("plateCount");
    fireEvent.change(plateCount, { target: { value: 2 } });
    let bookedOnDate = screen.getByTestId("bookedOn");
    fireEvent.change(bookedOnDate, { target: { value: "2022-03-25" } });

    let form = screen.getByTestId("buffet-form");
    fireEvent.submit(form);
    let successMessage = await screen.findByTestId("success");
    expect(successMessage.innerHTML).toContain(`1018`);
  });
  it("Testing axios post call error", async () => {
    server.use(
      rest.post("http://localhost:4000/bookings", (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(ctx.status(500));
      })
    );

    render(<BookingComponent />);
    let buffetName = screen.getByTestId("buffetName");
    fireEvent.change(buffetName, {
      target: { value: "SouthIndianFestivalSpecial" },
    });
    let email = screen.getByTestId("emailId");
    fireEvent.change(email, { target: { value: "kavya@gmail.com" } });
    let plateCount = screen.getByTestId("plateCount");
    fireEvent.change(plateCount, { target: { value: 2 } });
    let bookedOnDate = screen.getByTestId("bookedOn");
    fireEvent.change(bookedOnDate, { target: { value: "2022-03-25" } });

    let form = screen.getByTestId("buffet-form");
    fireEvent.submit(form);
    let errorMessage = await screen.findByTestId("error");
    expect(errorMessage.innerHTML).toContain("Something went wrong");
  });
});
```

This is my jsx file where i gather data on onChange in form
when submit button clicked it goes to handleSubmit function given below
the function check input values and post the data to josn-server using axios

```
    console.log("buffet button clicked");
    // 1. This method will be invoked when user clicks on 'Book Buffet' button.
    // 2. You should prevent page reload on submit
    // 3. check whether all the form fields are entered. If any of the form fields is not entered set the mandatory state variable to true.
    // 4.  If all the form fields values are entered then make axios call to
    // "http://localhost:4000/bookings/" and pass the appropriate state as data to the axios call
    // 5. If the axios call is successful, assign the below string to successMessage state:
    //   "Booking is successfully created with bookingId: " + <id>
    // 6. If the axios call is not successful, assign the error message to "Something went wrong"
    e.preventDefault();
    let allfiesds =
      formErrors.emailIdError &&
      formErrors.bookedOnError &&
      formErrors.buffetNameError &&
      formErrors.plateCountError;
    setMandatory(allfiesds ? true : false);
    // working but not qualifying in testing
    if (valid) {
      axios
        .post(url, state)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          setSuccessMessage(
            "Booking is successfully created with bookingId: " + res.data.id
          );
          setErrorMessage("");
          console.log(res.data.id);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response) {
            console.log(error.response.data.message);
          }
          setErrorMessage(messages.ERROR);
          setSuccessMessage("");
          console.log();
        });
    }
  };
```

this is error im getting in testing

```
 Testing Booking component post http call › Testing axios post call success

    expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

    Expected substring: "1018"
    Received string:    ""

      203 |     fireEvent.submit(form);
      204 |     let successMessage = await screen.findByTestId("success");
    > 205 |     expect(successMessage.innerHTML).toContain(`1018`);
          |                                      ^
      206 |   });
      207 |   it("Testing axios post call error", async () => {
      208 |     server.use(

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:205:38)

  ● Testing Booking component post http call › Testing axios post call error

    expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

    Expected substring: "Something went wrong"
    Received string:    ""

      227 |     fireEvent.submit(form);
      228 |     let errorMessage = await screen.findByTestId("error");
    > 229 |     expect(errorMessage.innerHTML).toContain("Something went wrong");
          |                                    ^
      230 |   });
      231 | });
      232 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:229:36)
```